# Start location service with dispatch_once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

I want to ask the user's location only once due the app launching life.
I mean, each time the user launch the app, ask for his location service (only once).

I thought to do so with `dispatch_once`.

```
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
});
```

Is it the best way to do so? Or there is a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is this code? Why are you worried that it might run more than once and what would the side effect be if it did?

Comment: Thanks @Wain, This code is in place that can be occur several time. And I'm not worry, I ask about the best practice... The side effect should be the location question for the user (and I know it asks just once, but the timing of the question is matter to me)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you shouldn't need to worry about calling `startUpdatingLocation` multiple times. Instead what you should do is to add logic to ensure that it's only called if appropriate - i.e. after it becomes meaningful to the user.

Generally, this means storing some state, perhaps in user defaults, and checking that state before calling `startUpdatingLocation`. In particular the state would only be set once the user has reached a particular stage in your app where it's sensible to ask them for permission (and that they have approved, though this check needs to be made more frequently as they could later decide to revoke auth rights).